# If a cell ends in a certain word, how do I delete the entire row? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that has over 10,000 rows. I would like to run a VBA script that deletes all rows in which column `B` **ends** in the word `reduce`. For example if my column looks like this:

```
CostReduce
PriceReduce
ReducePrice
MaterialReduce
InfrastructureReduce
ReduceProfits
ReduceOverhead
```

I would like the script to run and delete every row that has a word that ends in `Reduce`. So the output would be:

```
ReducePrice
ReduceProfits
ReduceOverhead
```

The script that I have right now deletes all rows that contain the word reduce, and I'm not sure how I can go about altering it so it does what I want.

```
Sub DeleteReduce()

Dim ContainWord As String

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

ContainWord = "reduce"

Do While Range("B" & i) <> ""
    If Not Range("B" & i).Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: replace you instruction ´If Not Range("B" & i).Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then´ by ´if range("B" & i) like "*" & containword then´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Right` function, minor change to your VB:

```
Sub DeleteReduce()

Dim ContainWord As String

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

ContainWord = UCase("reduce")

Do While Range("B" & i) <> ""
    If UCASE(right(Range("B" & i).value,len(ContainWord))) = ContainWord Then
        Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Updated to remove case sensitivity

Comment: I like this solution, and can see the logic behind it, but it's throwing an error on this line: `If Not Right(Range("B" & i), Len(ContainWord)) = ContainWord Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @Abtra16 Please check now, I removed the 'is nothing' part which is no longer useful.  Also made it case in-sensitive

Comment: You should probably also delete the "Not" in the condition, else it will delete all but the line ending with the keyword:)

Comment: Thank you very much! @EoinS

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a script? Would it not suffice to introduce another column with simple =IF(RIGHT(B1, 6)="reduce","yes","no") and apply a filter, then delete the rows with "yes" values?

Comment: I appreciate this! But I am trying to do it in a VBA script.

Answer (score 0):

Have it check the last 6 characters in the cell and see if they match Reduce.

`Right(Range("B" & i ),6) = "Reduce"`

```
Sub DeleteReduce()
Dim ContainWord As String
Dim i As Integer

  ContainWord = "Reduce"

  Do While Range("B" & i) <> ""
    If Right(Range("B" & i ),6) = ContainWord Then
      Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Loop
  Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Trying changing "reduce" to "Reduce"

Comment: Is there a blank space at the end of it perhaps?

Comment: Disregard my last comment, it works. It just wasn't in cell B2 cuz i was testing it. thanks!

Comment: You need also to add "i=i-1" to the succesful condition because the row deletion will otherwise cause the macro to skip lines (Row3 gets a positive result, so gets deleted - next Row4 becomes Row3 but the iteration goes to the Row4, i.e. original Row5). For case insensitivity, just put it OR in the condition with the other option.

Comment: Modified Rdster's answer, now the code should work perfectly.

Comment: I put it back, in my haste to condense the code, I failed to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `Autofilter` to set a `Range` with the `Rows` to be deleted, then presents two methods to delete the rows:

1. Deleting entire range at once: However this could be slow depending on the quantity of areas, size of the file, etc.
2. Deleting the resulting range by Area in Ascending Order (Bottom to Top).

Both methods are "active" in the code below, you need to comment the method no chosen.

```
Sub Rows_Delete_EndingWord_Published()
Dim sCriteria As String
sCriteria = "Reduce"    'Change as required
Dim rDta As Range, rTmp As Range
Dim l As Long

    Application.Calculate
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Rem Set Data Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht(0)")  'Change as required
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
        Set rDta = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown))
    End With

    Rem Filter Data Range & Set Resulting Range
    With rDta
        Set rTmp = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count, 1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & sCriteria
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rTmp = rTmp.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Rem Delete Filtered Data
    Rem Presenting two methods - need to uncomment the method chosen
    If Not (rTmp Is Nothing) Then

        Rem Method 1 - Deleting entire range at once
        Rem However it could be slow depending on the quantity of areas, size of the file, etc.
        rTmp.EntireRow.Delete

        Rem Method 2 - Deleting the range by Area in Ascending Order (Bottom to Top)
        For l = rTmp.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
            rTmp.Areas(l).EntireRow.Delete
        Next

    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This is so delightfully complex!

Comment: Probably, but do not be afraid of learning. It's highly efficient working with objects especially when semi large\large data is involved. this code selects the required data and deletes them at once instead of running endless loops.